# replace special characters in java

Tags: java, text

I have an Arabic string, that I need to remove all special characters, LATIN ALPHABET , punctuation e.g. (, . ;) ,and Arabic punctuation e.g. (َ ً ُ ِ) I have wrote the following code

```
     String input = "some text";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\w]");
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {   
    }
    m.reset();
    input = m.replaceAll(" ");


     p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Mn}\\p{Nd}\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}]+");
     m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
    }
    m.reset();
    input = m.replaceAll("");
```

it worked will for almost all characters, but I still have problems removing or replacing those ($ ^ + < > |), I don't want to remove each one apart by repeating replaceAll statement,  I even tried

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+");
```

also kept finding those in the resulting text ($ ^ + < > |), any way to do it?

Comment: would it be easier to invert the problem and specify only unicode region with characters that you want to keep ?

Comment: can you please post your sample input and output?

Comment: There's no such thing as "English language characters."  English uses the ROMAN ALPHABET, also known as the LATIN ALPHABET.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by still having problems? Have you tried simply escaping the characters? Also, does this have anything to do with the [tag:processing] language?

Comment: @ JavaHopper.    
input : أبو محمود >العماوي< لا يستطيع | ولا يقدر $$ على القيام + بهذا = ابداً ؟ وبكل المحاولات 7 
output:  ابو محمود > عماو < استطيع | يقدر $$ قيام + = ابد محاول